# How to get tag value by tag name using web scraping in Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I do daily analysis of eCommerce sites and I have to copy their prices.

All i wanna do is, i paste the URL of a website into an Excel worksheet and I get prices from the tag name in the cell. The source of site looks like this:

```
<table>
<td>
Price
</td>
<td>
:
</td>
<td>
<input name="Price" type="text" value="148.0000" id="uxMSRPPrice1" style="width: 250px;" />
(In x.xx format)
</td>
</table>
```

and I want to get price 148.0000 in my worksheet, using tag name="Price"
price is unique tag in source

One more thing, I can only get source from the URL like this including view-source (I cant share the original client URL so i change it to `xyz`):

```
https://www.xyz com/admin/ProductPage.aspx?ProductID=xxx
```

Comment: welcome at Stackoverflow. You are asking a complete solution for a complex problem (open web-page from url, open its source, find tag, extract value to excel). What exactly is your problem? What've you already tried to achieve? Please note that as it is currently your question likely will be closed as too broad.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i already solved this problem. (after asking this question here)

Comment: could you please post your answer too? that would help also others to benefit from it. Otherwise if you don't want to publish it then please remove your question instead of just abandoning it.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Public Sub GetValueFromBrowser()
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
Dim ie As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim selling As String
    Dim cost As String
    url = Selection.Value
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
      .Visible = 1
      .navigate url
       While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
         DoEvents
       Wend
    End With

    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = ie.document

    selling = Trim(Doc.getElementsByName("sellingPrice")(0).Value)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = selling
    cost = Trim(Doc.getElementsByName("costPrice")(0).Value)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = cost
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: change ".Visible=1" to "Visible=0"